# How do I get UCameraComponent from ACharacter/APlayerController?

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4

I am pretty new to both UE4 and C++ so maybe my question is kinda stupid, but how do I get UCameraComponent if I have my custom AMainCharacter class inherited from ACharacter and my custom AMainPlayerController inherited from APlayerController? Actually all I need is CameraLocation and CameraTransform. So just getting CameraLocation and its FTransform fits me as well, any suggestions?

By the way I tried surfing Unreal Documentation and found APlayerCameraManager class, but I could not connect it as well.

Thanks for your help in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on where you defined your camera component? Is it in c++ or in blueprint? Where did you attach it? I would recommend to learn a bit more about how to create components in C++.

If you created and attached your Component in C++ you'd have a variable such as PlayerCamera that you made.

So i assume you've added your camera component in blueprints. To access that camera you have to get the actor components by class and search the component you need.

```
TArray<UCameraComponent*> CameraComps;
GetComponents<UCameraComponent>(CameraComps);
```

And now `CameraComps` **array** holds your camera components.

This is more complicated than just creating your component in c++ and attaching it.

Here is a tutorial how to do it.

https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-US/Programming/Tutorials/PlayerCamera/1/index.html

Comment: I used c++ only, but the thing is I did not created my CameraComponent, I have my camera attached to my custom ACharacter class, so there's no variable available. But actually tutorial with link you given works, so I managed to do all things I had to do, thanks

Comment: Defining a normal `TArray` didn't work for me, so I used a `TInlineComponentArray` instead

Comment: There was a typo in the code missing a *

Answer (score 1):

Just a little correction :

```
TArray<UCameraComponent*> CameraComps;
```

It's a pointers array of UCameraComponent.

Comment: Thanks for telling me how to get 2 free reputation with an edit :]